# How to get index(or count of indexes) on a temp table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please note the following is with JDBC.
A temp table #TEMP_NOTIF is create like this.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_NOTIF') IS NOT NULL TRUNCATE TABLE #TEMP_NOTIF ELSE CREATE TABLE #TEMP_NOTIF (ID varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

An index IX_TEMP is created on above table.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TEMP_NOTIF ON #TEMP_NOTIF (ID ASC)
```

The above two operation should run in a loop(cleaning up old tuples). Creating table is fine(it truncates if table already exists) but the problem is with Index(Index should be created on first time only). How to find whether an index(or count of indexes) exist on a temp table or not? I've tried using

```
select * from sys.indexes where name='IX_TEMP_NOTIF'
```

but no tuples returned.

I'm using SQL SERVER 2012.
Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? you know if you need to create an index - i.e if the table does not exist, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: @AlexK. Those two queries are in a java method. On second iteration it is failing by stating index already exist on the table. I'm looking for a query it creates index only if it's not created already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first SQL statement knows to look in `tempdb` for the temporary *table*, so your subsequent statement should look in `tempdb` for the *index* on that table:

```sql
select * from tempdb.sys.indexes where name='IX_TEMP_NOTIF'
```

Comment: Tried with above query, still zero rows.

Comment: Yes, its working. I was looking for wrong index. Thank you @GordThompson.